# Problem with using generics for static deserialization

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have a pretty rudimentary understanding of using generics, so bear with me.

I have an abstract class, `AMob`, that a bunch of other "monster" classes extend. Each mob must have a static `deserialize` method to convert from map to mob object as well as a non-static `serialize` method to convert this mob object to a map. I wanted to create the static `deserialize` in the abstract `AMob` class so that I don't need to recreate it for every different monster.

*Signature for class AMob*

```
public abstract class AMob<T>
```

*Signature for an example classes for monsters*

```
public class Monster1 extends AMob<Monster1> {}
public class Monster2 extends AMob<Monster2> {}
public class Monster3 extends AMob<Monster3> {}
// ...
```

What I want is to be able to deserialize an arbitrary child class of AMob via the static `deserialize` method and return the child as the correct type. This is what I have right now inside `AMob<T>`:

```
public static <T> AMob<T> deserialize(Map<String, Object> map)
{
    return (AMob<T>) deserializeHelper(map, new Monster1());
}

public static <T> AMob<T> deserializeHelper(Map<String, Object> map, AMob<T> mob) 
{
    // ..
}

public Map<String, Object> serialize()
{
    // ...
}
```

The obvious problem is that every deserialized mob will become an instance of `Monster1`; instead I'd want to do something like `return (AMob<T>) deserializeHelper(map, new T());` but I can't do that. My intent with that is to get the type passed in via `T` and create a new instance of that type to deserialize to. I'm not sure if giving a generic parameter to a static method even works the way I would think it does. The only reason I even introduced a generic parameter to `AMob` in the first place was to try to only have to write `deserialize` once and have it dynamically create the correct child object.

Are there any suggestions on what I should do differently? Is this even possible for what I'm trying to do? If there are any questions regarding my issue let me know.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have `class Monster1 extends AMob<Monster1>`. The class is already `Monster1`, you aren't gaining anything by passing that exact same type to the `AMob` type parameter. I don't think it will possible for you to perform this sort of polymorphic deserialization without manually inspecting each subclass with reflection to figure out what the map should be deserialized into.

Comment: Are you hell bent on creating your own deserialize logic? This problem is actually already solved with Jackson, here's a great article on how to do it with that if you choose to use a library instead: https://medium.com/@david.truong510/jackson-polymorphic-deserialization-91426e39b96a

Comment: I do not think this recursive definition is correct: `public class Monster1 extends AMob<Monster1> {}`

Comment: Show the definition of AMob with just the method signatures.

Comment: @Flaom what would I use instead to define extension of AMob?

Comment: @Tarik I just edited and added the signature for `deserializeHelper` since I forgot to include that. I'm not sure why the other methods are relevant? They're just specific operations for the class.

Comment: @Floam I'd be open to a library I suppose, this is just for a Minecraft plugin so they have YML configuration operations already (deserialize and serialize methods get called automatically).

Comment: You would just remove generics and have regular inheritance. Ok if you are going to use built in deserialize methods, I would go the route of using reflection to gather the properties of each subclass (perhaps in a static block so it only runs once?) and compare those properties to the map's keys to figure out what subclass the map should be turned into

Comment: Please, post AMob class with method signatures and empty curled brackets. return null when there is a return value. Ensure it compiles.